# Return product variation attribute values names (without hyphens)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

to get Product Variations in WooCommerce, I'm using:

```
$product->get_available_variations();
```

But I'm getting results with hyphens, see this screenshot:

[image]

How can I get results without hyphens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, WooCommerce is displaying in this case, the attributes slugs values, then it replace spaces by hyphens and uppercase by lowercase, what is completely normal. So what you would like is to display the attributes names (and not the slugs).

For that you can use [**`get_term_by( 'slug', $slug_value, $taxonomy )`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to get first the object of values and then the name value...

1) You can check that **`get_term_by()`** function is really working with that code:

```
$term_value = get_term_by( 'slug', 'copper-stp-10100base-ttx', 'pa_sfp-module' );
echo $term_value->name; // will display the name value
```

**2) Then your specific code is going to be:**

```
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

$attributes = $variations['attributes'];

// Iterating through each attribute in the array
foreach($attributes as $attribute => $slug_value){

    // Removing 'attribute_' from Product attribute slugs
    $term_attribute = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attribute);

    // Get the term object for the attribute value
    $attribute_value_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug_value, $term_attribute );

    // Get the attribute name value (instead of the slug)
    $attribute_name_value = $attribute_value_object->name

    // Displaying each attribute slug with his NAME value:
    echo 'Product attribute "' . $term_attribute . '" has as name value: ' . $attribute_name_value . '<br>';

}
```

This is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this : 

$taxonomy = 'pa_powercord';
    $meta = get_post_meta($available_variations[0]['variation_id'], 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, true);
    echo $meta;
    $term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);

    

    print_r($term);


But it's returning me this array : 

WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 94
    [name] => North America
    [slug] => north-america
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 94
    [taxonomy] => pa_powercord
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 8
    [filter] => raw
    [term_order] => 0
)

Comment: So, How can I get taxonomy name formatted, instead of pa_powercord?

Comment: Nah! I found a way, Thanks. :)